# How do I remove my login account from stack exchange network?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

I need to remove my Google [login](https://stackexchange.com/users/2142001/bala) from Stack Exchange network, how can I do that ? I need only my facebook login and that Google login is associated with my previous company email id.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hmmmm yaa very silly I just visited [my user page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/12418/bala) and then able to remove the login account easily.

[image]